# "Batch job submission failed: Access/permission denied" when submitting a slurm job inside a slurm script

Tags: nested, slurm, hpc, sbatch

I have three slurm scripts:
1.slurm:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=first
#SBATCH --partition=cuda.q

sbatch 2.slurm
```

2.slurm:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=second
#SBATCH --partition=cuda.q

sbatch 3.slurm
```

3.slurm

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=third
#SBATCH --partition=cuda.q

echo "a"
```

Only the 1.slurm job is submitted and in the output file I get the error:
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Access/permission denied

Comment: This works fine with Slurm on the HPC systems I use but it depends on how Slurm has been setup and configured on the HPC system. I suggest you contact the support team for the HPC service you are using with this question.

Comment: Can the `2.slurm` job be submitted successfully on its own? (I.e. not inside job 1)

Answer (score 0):

Your cluster isn't configured to allow job submission from a compute host. One workaround that might work is to SSH back to the head node and submit the job from there.

File 1.slurm might look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=first
#SBATCH --partition=cuda.q

ssh ${USER}@LOGIN_NODE sbatch 2.slurm
```